# Dealing With Multiple Instances Of Partial Views And Model Binding In ASP.NET MVC 4 Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my controller code.

```
namespace MultipleInstance.Controllers
{
    public class Default1Controller : Controller
    {
     private MVCDemoEntities db = new MVCDemoEntities();

   public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Order ord = new Order();
        //ord.BillingAddress = new Address1();
        //ord.ShippingAddress = new Address();
        return View(ord);
    }

   public ActionResult ProcessForm(Order ord)
   {

       return PartialView("Index");

       }


    }
}
```

This is my Index View.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("ProcessForm","Default1",FormMethod.Post))
{
  <h3>Basic Details</h3>
  @Html.Partial("_BasicDetails")
  <h3>Shipping Address</h3>
  @Html.Partial("_Address", 
  new ViewDataDictionary() 
  { 
    TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo() 
      { HtmlFieldPrefix = "ShippingAddress" } })


      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

this is my two partial views _BasicDetails.cshtml and _Address.cshtml

```
@model MultipleInstance.Order

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.OrderID_)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OrderID_)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.CustomerID_)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CustomerID_)</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is _Address.cshtml view.

```
@model MultipleInstance.Address

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Street1)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Street1)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Street2)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Street2)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Country)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Country)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.PostalCode)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PostalCode)</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When i run the above code following error comes. The partial view '_BasicDetails' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. Can anyone help me where i am going wrong? Or do i need to change anything in my action method?

This is my model class

```
public partial class Order
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string OrderID_ { get; set; }
        public string CustomerID_ { get; set; }
        public string SelectType { get; set; }
        public Address ShippingAddress { get; set; }

    }



public partial class Address
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Street1 { get; set; }
        public string Street2 { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the path of your partial view

Comment: and what is the path of your index view

Comment: ~Views\shared\_BasicDetails.cshtml

Comment: ~Views\Default1\Index.cshtml

Comment: have you tried to use this  `@Html.Partial("_BasicDetails")` with the full path of your partial view ?

Comment: This is the path of partial view. ~Views\Shared\_BasicDetails.cshtml

Comment: ex:  `@Html.Partial("~Views\shared\_BasicDetails.cshtml")`

Comment: Yes I tried with all possibilities

Comment: Hi I changed as below and now it is working fine.

Comment: @Html.Partial("~/Views/_BasicDetails.cshtml") and  @Html.Partial("~/Views/_Address.cshtml", 
  new ViewDataDictionary() 
  { 
    TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo() 
      { HtmlFieldPrefix = "ShippingAddress" } })

Comment: Thanks for help guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work

```
@Html.Partial("~Views/shared/_BasicDetails.cshtml", Model)
```

and you need to pass it the model [and it should be initialized in your action] because as I see in you code you are consuming it in your partial view

Comment: Yes Both way works. Can anyone tell me how to save data of all tables to db?

Comment: Do i need to write seperate action method? I am using Entity framework. Please give me some idea

Comment: as a best practice, keep you model view controller clean from any business related coding, i.e: create a business model that communicate with your database layers, weather it is entity framework or any other mean, and just call this business model in your controller, ex: `Employees.GetDetails()` to use it in a view that shows one employee details,  and `Employees.ListAll()` to get a list of employees you have...etc

Comment: [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ProcessForm(Order ord)
       {
           if (ModelState.IsValid)
           {
               db.Orders.Add(ord);
               db.SaveChanges();
           }
           return View(ord);
      I wrote below code to save data but values are getting inserting to only orders table but not to address page.

Comment: So i need to create sepearate class for business related codes and i should call each time whenever required??

Comment: Yea, your action should deal with a business class, and your business class should do the dirty work

Comment: Okay thank you. I have added this logic to add data to both tables.  if If(ModelState.IsValid)
               {
                   db.Orders.Add(ord);
                   db.Addresses.Add(ord.ShippingAddress);
                   db.SaveChanges();
               }          but ord.ShippingAddress giving error.

Comment: Please tell me how to save all data to tables? What implementation i need to make in below action method?  public ActionResult ProcessForm(Order ord,Address add)
       {
          
           return View(ord);


       }

Comment: You need a model class that contains all the data you need to save! passing Order object only will lack the other details you need!

Comment: Create a class, add all the info you need, age, salary, address, whatever, pass this model to your view, and accept it as a parameter in your action, then use it to fill your Order object and any other related objects